# Composer and Git - How to set stability

Tags: wordpress, git, github, composer-php, versioning

I'm new to GIT and reasonably new composer. Right now I am trying to pull a dependancy from a GIT repository I created. The reason for this is the site I am building is wordpress and this repository holds a plugin which is not currently available online. The issue is I get this error message:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

I know this is due to the default stability in composer being stable and my repository not being recognised as a stable version. I would like to keep the stability in composer as it is, and change the GIT repository so that it is recognised as a stable version. There has been one commit to the repository, this is the inital upload of the plugin, plus I have given it a tag with a version number, which is currently V5.2.6.

For extra reference here is my current composer file:

```
"name": "install/wordpress",
"description": "Wordpress site.",
"repositories": [
{
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "plugins/custom-plugin",
    "version": "master",
    "type": "wordpress-plugin",
    "dist": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://user_ready_only:thepassword@bitbucket.org/plugins/custom-plugin.git",
      "reference": "master"
    }
  }
},

"extra": {
"wordpress-install-dir": "wp",
"installer-paths": {
  "web/plugins/{$name}/": ["plugins/custom-plugin"]
}
},

"require": {
"php": ">=5.4",
"composer/installers": "~1.0",
"johnpbloch/wordpress": "~4.2.",
"plugins/custom-plugin": "5.2.6"
}
}
```

(I have modified the above to remove secure information) Thank you in advance for any feedback :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what ended up working for me:

```
{
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "plugins/custom-plugin",
    "version": "5.2.6",
    "type": "wordpress-plugin",
    "source": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://user_ready_only:thepassword@bitbucket.org/plugins/custom-plugin.git",
      "reference" : "v5.2.6"
    }
  }
},
```

I had to change "dist" to source and reference the version tag as opposed to master. Hopefully this will help someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the "package" type to reference external repositories. Use the "vcs" type and only give the URL of the repository. That way you allow Composer to autodetect all necessary metadata.

Using "package", you provide all metadata in the `composer.json`, disabling any detecting in the repository itself. So it doesn't matter if you tag anything there - it will be ignored. Everything inside that "package" definition should go into the `composer.json` of that package in the repository, apart from "version" (the version should always be taken from the tag or branch name) and "dist" (that is automatically resolved by Composer for Bitbucket).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Sven. I changed the type to vcs and referenced the URL (including user name and password, as its a private repo) but the same error persists.

Comment: I'm never quite sure if Composer does retain data from previous installations. For a fresh start you'd have to delete the vendor folder and `composer.lock` and try `composer update`. Or create a new project in a new directory with a minimal `composer.json` that only contains the "repositories" entry and `"require":{"plugins/custom-plugin":"5.2.6"}` Maybe this is still failing due to missing authentication with your Bitbucket repo.